# What does "generally" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: adverbs

> We can see why the non-reductive understanding of the computational theory fits into scientific theorizing generally.

What is the reference of "generally" exactly? Fits or theorizing?

Comment: *Fits*. *Theorizing* is a noun. It cannot be modified by an adverb.

Comment: @ЯegDwight This would be a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

This could actually be tricky, if the word *scientific* weren't there. Luckily it is.

*Scientific* is an adjective, and as such clearly marks *theorizing* as a noun. This in turn means that it cannot be modified by *generally*, which is an adverb.

You can still modify *theorizing* by other adjectives, including *general*. But adverbs just don't work on nouns.

And so we can conclude that *generally* modifies *fits*.

Answer (score 0):

The word "generally" has two meanings dependent on context.

The first context is regular English use, in which "generally" means "usually" or "ordinarily" and without concern for specifics: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generally

The second is a scientific or mathematical context, in which "generally" means "in the general case" in which there are no exceptions. (This is as opposed to special cases, which do not hold true in general.)  So in this context, "generally" means "always, in every case".

This example appears to be in a scientific/mathematical context, so it means that "non-reductive understanding of the computational theory" is a special case of the more general "scientific theorizing".